# How to make ngx-charts-gauge tooltip apear near to arc when [showAxis]="false"

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ngx-charts

i am using ngx-charts-gauge with single result set, i have set   [showAxis]="false" as i dont want axis. but on hover of arc tootip displays far away from arc.

I tried with #tooltipTemplate as but no luck.

```
below is my chart 

<ngx-charts-gauge
[scheme]="colorScheme"
[results]="single"
[min]="0"
[max]="100"
[angleSpan]="240"
[startAngle]="-120"
[units]="'alerts'"
[bigSegments]="10"
[smallSegments]="5"
[legend]="true"
[showAxis]="false"
(select)="onSelect($event)"
</ngx-charts-gauge>
```

below is my data source

[image]   single = [
    {
      "name": "German",
      "value": 8940000,
      "data":[
        {"placement": "bottom"}
      ]

```
  }
 ];
colorScheme = {
domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C']
  };
```